# How to stop writes to a MongoDB but allow reads

Tags: mongodb

I have a ver2.6 shared MongoDB cluster with replica sets.
We need to make a backup (using mongodump) for DB migration, but to minimize impact to the the users, we would like to allow reads to the DB, while stopping writes.

We assumed `db.fsyncLock()` would do what we expected, but it looks like it prevents reads as well.
For example, when the db is locked with fsyncLock(), I cannot even to `show dbs` in the mongo console.

Is there another way to stop writes to a sharded Mongo cluster, while allowing reads to happen?

Thank you.

Comment: Perform the backup against the locked secondary. Follow the [Back Up a Sharded Cluster with File System Snapshots](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-sharded-cluster-with-filesystem-snapshots/). The procedure is the same, no matter if you run the backup with snaphot or mongodump. If you really need to stop write operations, then shut down half of the nodes. Then the primary goes to secondary, i.e. goes to read/only.

Comment: Thank you @WernfriedDomscheit.
Does it mean that if each shard is a 3-node replica set, if I shut down 2 of the nodes, the remaining node will be read only?
The documentation says ```To lock or freeze a sharded cluster, you shut down one member of each replica set.```. Why does it say 1-member?

Comment: A replica set is able to elect a primary (i.e. permits write operations) if the **majority** of all members is reachable. So, for a 3 member Replica set you must shut down or disconnect 2 members.

Comment: "minimize impact to the users" is contradicting to "stopping writes" - what do you actually like to get?

Comment: Thank you @WernfriedDomscheit
Minimize the impact in the sense that the users will still be able to do most of the operations as long as the application can perform reads from DB.

Comment: Then I would suggest the procedure I provided in my first comment. It does not impact the application at all.